# How to join result of different taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I need to search properties by cities and areas at the same time. So I created two query to take all the references of the cities, and the areas:

```
$city_query = "SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->terms t
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'property-city' AND LOWER(t.name) LIKE '%s' ";
$like = '%colorado%';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($city_query, $like), OBJECT);
$city_ids = array(); 

foreach($result as $city)
{
    array_push($city_ids, $city->term_id);
}

$area_query = "SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->terms t
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'property-area' AND LOWER(t.name) LIKE '%s' ";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($area_query, $like), OBJECT);
$area_ids = array(); 

foreach($result as $area)
{
    array_push($area_ids, $area->term_id);
}
```

until here there is no problem 'cause I taken only the reference of the taxonomies. The problem is here:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'zoacres-property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $city_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property-area',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $area_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$found_posts = $query->found_posts;
```

Essentially, this query isn't returning anything 'cause there are no properties for `colorado` which have as `taxonomy` area, but there are only properties in city taxonomy.

Is it possible to return the results that there are at least in a taxonomy, but searching for all of them?